# Save to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Drive used to show up as a “save” option on my computer, but now it's gone. I can go to Drive view and view and download docs, even docs shared with me.

I tried loading Drive for PC, but still it doesn't show. Without it, how can I save docs to Drive?

Comment: Were the items synced to your desktop before or was this entirely cloud-based?

Answer (score 2):

By installing the Google Drive in your pc, you can just drag the files onto the drive icon and you should be able to save it to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can save files to Google Drive simply by moving/copying them to the special "Google Drive" folder on your hard drive.

Or, go to the web interface and use the upload feature.

[image: upload button]